# Input value not getting picked up in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**header.php**

```
 <div id="rename-content" class="hide">
    <form class="popover-form">
      <div class="popover-form-content">
        <div class="material-input-group stretched">
          <input type="text" placehold="Title" id="new-row-name">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="popover-footer pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default flat close-popover">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default flat rename-row">Rename</button>   
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```

**footer.php**
In `$(document).ready()`

```
        $('.edit-row-lbl').popover({
          title: "Rename Row",
          content: function(){
            return $("#rename-content").html();
          },
          html: true,
          placement: 'bottom',
          trigger: 'manual'
        });

        $('.edit-col-lbl, .edit-row-lbl').click(function()
        {
            if ($(this).hasClass('edit-col-lbl') )
            {
                to_rename = 'col';
                col_id_to_rename = $(this).data('col-id');
                $('.edit-col-lbl').popover('show');
            }
            else
            {
                to_rename = 'row';
                row_id_to_rename = $(this).data('row-id');
                $('.edit-row-lbl').popover('show');
            }

            $('.edit-col-lbl, .edit-row-lbl').not(this).popover('hide');
        });

        $('body').off().on('click', '.rename-row', function() 
        {
          var new_row_name = $('#new-row-name').val();

          console.log('Rename row clicked!');  
          console.log('New row name: ' + new_row_name);
          console.log('Row id to rename: ' + row_id_to_rename);

          $.ajax({
            type  : 'POST',
            url   : base_url + 'row/renameRow',
            data  : {
              'row_id' : row_id_to_rename,
              'row_name' : new_row_name
            },
            success: function(message) 
            {
              if (message == 'success') 
              {
                console.log('Renaming successful');
                window.location = window.location;
              }
              else
              {
                console.log('Error >> ' + message);
              }
            },
            error: function(xhr, error) 
            {
              console.log(xhr.responseText);
              console.log(error);
            }
          });
        });
```

In the console, the messages show up except that the row name is blank. I'm not getting any errors, just that the input is not getting picked up. When I try to print the value length it comes up as 1.

Comment: If you call `.val()` on an empty jQuery object it returns `undefined`, not "blank", so if you are getting blank that implies that jQuery did find the input in question. What value do you expect the input to have?

Comment: I input 'test' as a value so in the console it's supposed to show 'New row name: test'. There are really no validations yet set. Just need to make sure it gets into the database  @nnnnnn

Comment: A silly question, but... are `header.php` and `footer.php` both included on the same page? And presumably you're not getting a placeholder because of `placehold=` rather than `placeholder=`? Could that be 'corrupting' the `<input>`? Try fixing that to `placeholder` and see if that gets a valid input.

Comment: Yes, thanks for pointing out that typo with `placehold` I did correct it but the value still comes up as blank. I'm doing this in codeigniter, header and footer are loaded as views, but yeah I guess it's safe to say they're on the same page as they make up the template, including the content. @ObsidianAge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had to do this:

```
new_row_name = $('.popover #new-row-name').val();
```

bind it to the class. Now it picks up the value. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have variable 'row_id_to_rename' that is unknown inside your $('body') on click function.

You have to declare that variable at the top, outside of those functions:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var row_id_to_rename; // <- put here!
    $('.edit-row-lbl').popover({
        ...
    });
    $('.edit-col-lbl, .edit-row-lbl').click(function() {
        ...
    });
    $('body').off().on('click', '.rename-row', function() {
        ...
    });
});
```

Comment: The problem is with `new_row_name`, not `row_id_to_rename` ;)

Comment: I truncated my code. I do have that declared way above as I was trying it first with external js files, like this: `<script>
     var row_id_to_rename = 0;
 </script>
 <script src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/js/rows.js" type="text/javascript"></script>...`

Comment: Ah sorry, you haven't explained that, lol. I'll try to find the problem and make another answer, maybe, If I know the answer ;)

Comment: @herondale try to enter `$('#new-row-name').length` in your console. Is the result is 1?

Comment: @TaufikNurRahmanda yes, I typed 'test' and got 1 as the result after `.length`

Comment: @herondale this is odd. Maybe silly but try to type manually in your text input like "testing" or what, then enter `$('#new-row-name').val()` in the console. Don't say that the value not appear _(:"D

Comment: @herondale miracle is happening. How if you enter `$('#new-row-name').val('testing')`? how if you change your input id to another name? (just for testing)

Comment: I've tried your script in codeply and the value is appear good in the console. Maybe the problem is the another problem that's not even in your code you posted here.

Comment: @TaufikNurRahmanda i modified the value in the console like what you said and it got in and got stored in the database. you're right, maybe there's a conflict with the other scripts. thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

The input is being picked up is just that the value is the empty string.

```
<input type="text" placehold="Title" id="new-row-name">
```

If it would be not found in your console you would have seen 'New row name: undefined

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.edit-col-lbl, .edit-row-lbl').click(function()
        {
            if ($(this).hasClass('edit-col-lbl') )
            {
                to_rename = 'col';
                col_id_to_rename = $(this).data('col-id');
                $('.edit-col-lbl').popover('show');
            }
            else
            {
                to_rename = 'row';
                row_id_to_rename = $(this).data('row-id');
                $('.edit-row-lbl').popover('show');
            }

            $('.edit-col-lbl, .edit-row-lbl').not(this).popover('hide');
        });

        $('body').off().on('click', '.rename-row', function() 
        {
          var new_row_name = $('#new-row-name').val();

          console.log('Rename row clicked!');  
          console.log('New row name: ' + new_row_name);
                    
        });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="rename-content" class="hide">
    <form class="popover-form">
      <div class="popover-form-content">
        <div class="material-input-group stretched">
          <input type="text" placehold="Title" id="new-row-name">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="popover-footer pull-right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default flat close-popover">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default flat rename-row">Rename</button>   
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's confusing me is why is it blank even when I typed a value.

Comment: what text are you entering?

Comment: 'test', 'testing'. just simple strings. @artemisian

Comment: I've added a snippet and it's working just fine. Please check it out.

Comment: you're right. it's making little sense to me why the value comes up as blank, can't see what i'm missing out on. could it be because of one of the scripts im loading for customization?

Comment: It may be that one of the imported javascript libraries is interfering with jquery. Start disabling them one by one and check if the problem goes away